# Given $ye^{-{xe^{y-2x}}} = 2xe^{-x},$ where $x>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, y<\sqrt{2}$. Show that $y=y(x)$ decreases.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, implicit-function

Suppose $y$ is defined by the following implicit equation: $ye^{-{xe^{y-2x}}} = 2xe^{-x},$ where $x,y\geq 0.$

I want to show that $y$ decreases as $x$ increases, when $x>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y<\sqrt{2}$. Here is my work:

Suppose by contradiction that there exist some $x_1, x_2> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ such that $x_1<x_2 \implies y_1<y_2.$

From the above relation, we have
$$2x_1 = y_1e^{x_1(1-e^{y_1-2x_1})} \tag{1}$$
and
$$2x_2 = y_2e^{x_2(1-e^{y_2-2x_2})} .\tag{2}$$

Subtracting this results in the following:
$$2(x_2-x_1) = y_2e^{x_2(1-e^{y_2-2x_2})}- y_1e^{x_1(1-e^{y_1-2x_1})}.$$

From here, I am not sure how to proceed. The goal is to arrive at the contradiction $y_1>y_2$ with the assumption but getting this inequality seems somewhat challenging.

---

Following @jean's comment:

Take the natural logarithm on both sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$, and subtract:

\begin{align*}\ln{x_2}-\ln{x_1} &= \ln{y_2}-\ln{y_1} + x_2(1-e^{y_2-2x_2})- x_1(1-e^{y_1-2x_1})\\
& = \ln{y_2}-\ln{y_1} + (x_2-x_1) + (e^{y_1-2x_1}-e^{y_2-2x_2}).
\end{align*}

This looks much better compared to the exponential expression.

Comment: Why not studying the logarithm(s) of your expressions ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  Yes, I thought about that. I updated my post with the steps after taking logs. However, it is still not clear to me how to obtain the contradiction.

Comment: The title is both somewhat incoherent and different from the question stated in the body.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

**Fact 1.** $1 - xy\mathrm{e}^{y  - 2x} > 0$ on
$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \infty)\times (0, \sqrt{2})$.

**Fact 2.** For each fixed $x > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, the equation $
\ln y - x \mathrm{e}^{y-2x} = \ln 2 + \ln x - x$ has exactly one real solution $y \in (0, \sqrt{2})$.

$\phantom{2}$

Now, let
$$F(x, y) := \ln y - x \mathrm{e}^{y-2x} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x).$$
Clearly, $F(x, y)$ is continuously differentiable on $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \infty)\times (0, \sqrt{2})$. By Fact 1, we have
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{y}\left(1 - xy\mathrm{e}^{y  - 2x}\right) > 0.$$
By the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat237y1/20199/notes/Chapter3/S3.1.html), using Fact 2, the equation $F(x, y) = 0$ implicitly determines $y$ as a differentiable function of $x$, given that $x\in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \infty)$.

Taking derivative with respect to $x$ on
$\ln y - x \mathrm{e}^{y-2x} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) = 0$, we have
$$\frac{1}{y} \cdot y'(x)
- \mathrm{e}^{y-2x} - x \mathrm{e}^{y-2x}(y'(x) - 2)
- \frac{1}{x} + 1 = 0$$
or
$$\frac{1}{y}\left(1 - xy\mathrm{e}^{y  - 2x}\right)y'(x) = \frac{1}{x} + (1 - 2x)\mathrm{e}^{y - 2x} - 1. \tag{1}$$

From (1), using Fact 1, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{x} + (1 - 2x)\mathrm{e}^{y - 2x} - 1 < 0,$$
or
$$\mathrm{e}^{y - 2x} > \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\tag{2}$$
given that $(x, y) \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \infty)\times (0, \sqrt{2})$ with $\ln y - x \mathrm{e}^{y-2x} = (\ln 2 + \ln x - x)$.

Clearly, we only need to prove the case that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < x < 1$. (2) is written as
$$y > 2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}. \tag{3}$$
Clearly, we only need to prove the case that $2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} > 0$. Note that
$2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} < \sqrt{2}$
for all $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < x < 1$ (easy). By Fact 2, we have $y < \sqrt{2}$.

Let
$f(y) := \ln y - x \mathrm{e}^{y-2x} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x)$. By Fact 1, we have $f'(y) > 0$ on $(0, \sqrt{2})$, given that $x \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \infty)$.
Thus, we have
$$f(y) > f\left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right)
\iff y > 2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}$$
given that $2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\in (0, \sqrt{2})$, and $y \in (0, \sqrt{2})$. Using $f(y) = 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$0 > f\left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right),$$
or
$$\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) - x \cdot \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) < 0 \tag{4}$$
for all $x \in  (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1)$ with $2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} > 0$.

Note that $- x \cdot \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) < 1 - \ln 2$ for all $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < x < 1$.
We only need to prove the case that
$\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) + (1 - \ln 2) \ge 0$,
i.e. $2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} \ge \frac{2}{\mathrm{e}}$
which implies $x < 4/5$. Thus, it suffices to prove (4)
for $x \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac45)$.

Using $\ln (1 + u) \ge \frac{u}{2}\cdot \frac{2 + u}{1 + u}$ for all $-1 < u \le 0$, using $\frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} \in (0, 1)$, we have
$$\ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} \ge 
- \frac{(2x^2 - 2x + 1)(2x^2 - 1)}{2x(1 - x)(2x - 1)}.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$g(x) := \ln \left(2x - \frac{(2x^2 - 2x + 1)(2x^2 - 1)}{2x(1 - x)(2x - 1)}\right) - x \cdot \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) < 0.$$
(*Note*: $2x - \frac{(2x^2 - 2x + 1)(2x^2 - 1)}{2x(1 - x)(2x - 1)} > 0$ for all $x \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac45)$.)

We have
$$g'(x) = \frac{(2x^2 - 1)(24x^6 - 80x^5 + 116x^4 - 102x^3 + 56x^2 - 17x + 2)}{x(1 - x)(2x - 1)^2(-12x^4 + 16x^3 - 4x^2 - 2x + 1)} < 0.$$
Also, we have $g(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = 0$. Thus, $g(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac45)$.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to understand what's going on, especially in the last step. The goal is to prove the inequality (2), which in turn will justify why $y$ is decreasing in $x$. However, I am not sure what the last inequality implies. Are you saying, to prove (2), it suffices to prove the last inequality?

Comment: @Jane Yes. We only need to prove the case that $x < 1$ and $2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} > 0$. Note that $f(y)$ is strictly increasing. Thus, $y > 2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}$ is equivalent to $f(y) > f(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1})$, i.e. $0 > f(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1})$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That makes sense. But, why should $f(2x+ \ln{\dfrac{1/x -1}{2x-1}})<0$ be the case?

Comment: Yes, f(y)=0. My bad. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Yes, the inequality (2) is trivial for $x\geq 1$. Therefore, we only need to verify the last inequality for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}< x <1$

Comment: You have written 

"Note that $- x \cdot \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) < 1 - \ln 2$ for all $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < x < 1$. 
We only need to prove the case that
$\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) + (1 - \ln 2) \ge 0$" \\\\

Since $- x \cdot \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) < 1 - \ln 2$, then 
$$\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) - x \cdot \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) <\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) + (1 - \ln 2)$$

continuing..

Comment: So, we should show $\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) + (1 - \ln 2) \le 0$? In other words, shouldn't the required inequality be reversed?

Comment: @Jane No. If $\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) + (1 - \ln 2) < 0$, then (4) holds true, since $\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) - x \cdot \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) \le \ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right)  + (1 - \ln 2) < 0$, using the fact that $- x \cdot \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1} - (\ln 2 + \ln x - x) < 1 - \ln 2$. Thus, we focus on the case that $\ln \left(2x + \ln \frac{1/x - 1}{2x - 1}\right) + (1 - \ln 2)\ge 0$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Sorry, one more question: How to justify that $g^\prime(x)<0$? My guess is that the numerator is + and the denominator is - .

Comment: @Jane Yes, it suffices to prove that $h(x) := 24x^6 - 80x^5 + 116x^4 - 102x^3 + 56x^2 - 17x + 2 < 0$ for all $1/2 < x < 1$. We have $h'(x) = \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 72\,{x}^{4}-164\,{x}^{3}+150\,{x}^{2}-
78\,x+17 \right)  < 0$ since $72\,{x}^{4}-164\,{x}^{3}+150\,{x}^{2}-
78\,x+17 < 0$ (can you prove it?) .

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

An answer, which needs at the end a complementary study to be fully rigorous.

First of all, it is clear that setting $y=2x$ in the implicit equation gives $0$. Therefore, it is not surprizing that the following graphical representation of the implicit equation produced by GeoGebra has 2 branches : the straight line with equation $y=2x$ in blue and a hyperbola-looking branch in red.

[image]

*Fig. 1.*

By assuming that $y \ne 2x$, we can transform the initial equation into the following implicit equation which is the equation of the red branch the one of interest :

$$\frac{\ln(y)-\ln(2x)}{e^{y}-e^{2x}}=x e^{-2x}\tag{1}$$

The question is now : how can we prove that $y$ as defined by (1) can be given a cartesian equation $y=f(x)$ and that this function is a decreasing function of $x$ ?

Remark : this **functionality** issue (the existence of a unique $y$ for a given $x$) is assumed to be evident in the question but is not in fact ; it will be adressed later on.

Let us transform the LHS of (1) by setting

$$X=e^{2x}, \ \ Y=e^y \ \ \iff \ \ 2x=\ln X, \ \ y=\ln Y$$

giving :

$$\frac{\ln(\ln(Y))-\ln(\ln(X))}{Y - X}=\frac{\ln X}{2X} \tag{2}$$

Important : the domain is now $X>1$ and $Y>1$.

Setting

$$\varphi(X) := (\ln \circ \ln)(X) \ \ \text{(iterate log.) and } \ \ \psi(X)= \frac{\ln X}{2X}, $$

(with $\varphi'(X) = \frac{1}{X \ln(X)}$) relationship (2) can be written :

$$\frac{\varphi(Y)-\varphi(X)}{Y - X}= \psi(X)\tag{3}$$

**New solution :**

Let us consider the LHS of (3) as a "rate of change" (geometricaly the **slope** of line segment joining known point $A(X,\varphi(X))$ to point $B(Y,\varphi(Y))$ to be constructed ; see fig. 2 below).

The derivative $\varphi'$ is a bijective function (indeed, it is strictly decreasing) from $(1,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$ ; therefore we have, for each $X$, a (unique) value $X_0$ such that

$$\varphi'(X_0)=\psi(X)\tag{4}$$

giving to (3) the form :

$$\frac{\varphi(Y)-\varphi(X)}{Y - X}= \varphi'(X_0)\tag{5}$$

We can apply the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) (or more exactly a version of this theorem) allowing to conclude, due to its concavity, that, for any $X$, there exists a **unique** $Y$ such that the LHS of (5) is equal to its RHS, establishing in particular the functionality $Y=F(X)$ of the relationship of $X$ and $Y$, with, either :

$$X < X_0 <Y \ or \  Y < X_0 < X\tag{6}$$

Now, let us use a geometrical argument to see the pertinence of our approach (still not a rigorous proof along the standard "canons" of analysis). The closer $X$ is to value $1$ (i.e. the closer $x$ is to $0$), the farthest we have to take point $B(Y,\varphi(Y))$, i.e., as $X \to 1$, $Y \to \infty$.  In the other direction, when $X \to \infty$, $Y \to 1$. This establishes the asymptotes (see figure below where $f$ is for $\varphi$ and $g$ is for $\psi$).

[image]

*Fig. 2 : Caution : the domain of variables is here $X>1, \ Y>1$. The red curve is the image of the red curve of Fig. 1. Please note that function $\psi$ has on $(1,\infty)$ a minimum value $0$ and a maximal value $\tfrac{1}{2e}$.*

It remains to express rigorously the fact that $Y=F(X)$, not only has the right asymptotes, but is also decreasing ; this can almost surely be done in a rigorous way by bracketing the values (i.e., using inequalities "squeezing" the expressions like expression (6)). If I have some time, I will attempt to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the derivative of $\frac{1}{2} (x \ln{x}) (y-x)$. When simplify this out, we get $\frac{1}{2}  x y\ln{x}  - \frac{1}{2}  x^2 \ln{x}$. After differentiate, we have

$$\frac{1}{2} y^\prime x \ln{x}  + \frac{y}{2} (1+ \ln{x}) - x (\frac{1}{2} + \ln{x}).$$

Comment: There is also a typo in equation (1). It should be $xe^{-2x}$ on the right hand side.

Comment: With these changes, I get the following

$$Y^\prime \left( \dfrac{1}{Y \ln{Y}} - \dfrac{\ln{X}}{2X}          \right) = \dfrac{1}{X \ln{X}} + \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{Y(1- \ln{X})}{X^2} - \dfrac{1}{X}
   \right)$$

We can write this  as $Y^\prime\, u(X,Y) = v(X,Y)$, where 
$$ u(X,Y) = \dfrac{1}{Y \ln{Y}} - \dfrac{\ln{X}}{2X} $$ and $$v(X,Y)=\dfrac{1}{X \ln{X}} + \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{Y(1- \ln{X})}{X^2} - \dfrac{1}{X}
   \right)$$

Comment: I claim $u>0$ and $v<0$ for all $x>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y< \sqrt{2}$. Here is how I go about proving this. First, the argument for $u>0$. For fixed $Y$, it can easily be seen that $u$ is increasing in $X$. Therefore, 
$$u(X,Y) \geq u(e^{\sqrt{2}}, Y).$$
It remains to show that $u(e^{\sqrt{2}}, Y) \geq 0$. This is true since $u(e^{\sqrt{2}}, Y) $ is decreasing in $Y$. In particular, $$u(e^{\sqrt{2}}, e^{\sqrt{2}}) < u(e^{\sqrt{2}}, Y).$$ Since  $u(e^{\sqrt{2}}, e^{\sqrt{2}}) = 0$, we have the result.

Does my argument look correct?

Comment: 1) Thanks for correcting the typos (I am especialy prone to errors when it's late in the night). 2) Your argument(s) for $u$ are correct ; it should be similar for $v$. 3) It remains now to consider the other case $x \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y \ge \sqrt{2}$. 4) I have an idea of an alternate solution. If I have time, I will write it this morning.

Comment: I have written this new solution with a little "handwaving" at the end.

Comment: I have brought corrections to this new version (around formulas (4) and (5)).

Comment: Thanks. On a separate note, I tried to run the same argument to show $v<0$ in the desired regime. However, I am not able to fully justify that. In particular, I am having trouble with showing the inequality when $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}< x \leq 1$. I can do it for $x>1$.